# Using @BasePathAware on custom controller and enable RepositoryRestExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have some custom Controllers that add additional endpoints and operations for a service that utilizes Spring Data REST for the base implementation. I've annotated the Controller with `@BasePathAwareController` to make sure that the controller plays nice with SDR.

What I basically want is to leverage all of the error handling, validation, etc that SDR is providing, and I've build the controller so it calls the ApplicationEventPublisher the same way that the SDR controllers do for the base implementation. One issue is that when validation fails, the response is a 500 status, and instead of a 400 with the details of the validation messages encoded in JSON as I would expect.

I tried using `@RepositoryRestController` instead of `@BasePathAwareController`, but that didn't matter. Is there a way to configure the SDR exception handling for my own controllers without copying the code and re-implementing all of the logic?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085050/extend-repositoryrestexceptionhandler